# WHEA uncorrectable error BSOD and unable to boot into OS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bsod, crash

Even though this might not be the place for questions like this, I was hoping someone could help me.

Just yesterday I was using my laptop without a problem. Today I tried to boot into Windows and during booting, it just froze and gave me WHEA uncorrectable error BSOD. Every time I try to boot into Windows, it gets frozen. I dualboot Ubuntu and Ubuntu gets frozen during booting too. I tried system restore and system repair, but it failed.

The same thing happened before and I solved it by reinstalling OS completely. I would prefer not to do that. I also have access to GRUB shell if that would be any help. Thank you.

Comment: What flavor of Windows?

Comment: this is a fatal hardware issue. CPU is a good candidate for failing component.

Comment: @Moab Windows 10 in dualboot with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @magicandre1981 yeah, that's what that error should be. However, since the question was posted, I managed to get into Safe mode, which boots normally and runs completely normal. Because of that, I'd think maybe it's drivers problem? Would it be helpful to try uninstalling nonessential drivers and installing them again?

Comment: I have seen drivers cause this bug check also. See this...https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x124---whea-uncorrectable-error

Comment: Some suggestions here...https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-whea-uncorrectable-error-windows-10/

Comment: ok, if you can now boot, share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't have that file or folder. It isn't in the Windows folder (show hidden is turned on) nor does it show up in the search. I was also wondering, should I try uninstalling non-essential drivers (ones not used in safe mode)? Since safe mode boots, it is possible that the problem is in those drivers?

Comment: have you disabled pagefile? this is required to generate dumps

Comment: @magicandre1981 no, I remember turning it on on Windows. I realised that if I delete some of the drivers under System Devices in Device Manager, Windows will boot next time and suddenly stop like 10 seconds after it booted.

Comment: [check the KB page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/130536/windows-does-not-save-memory-dump-file-after-a-crash) for details what can cause Windows to not generate dumps